# Remove FCM token from Firebase device group

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Device group to notify all device of a user. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group

In order to stop notifications on a device I call:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
```

(see https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID)

The token is well deleted/invalidated for unique device message, if I notify this device with the firebase console we got an error message. 
However, the token is not deleted/invalidated from the firebase device group. If we notify the user's firebase device group this device is still notified.

I also tried to remove the token with the HTTP request (first link) on the device group, and it works. But, if the user logout offline and delete app data, I have no way to retrieve the previous user FCM group token to invalidate the current FCM token.

Do you have some advices?
Thank you.